# Automatically following an item via chatter when we create it or assign it?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed-tracking, community

My client is facing some issue to follow the record via chatter when someone assigns someone else an Opportunity, even though they have created it, they don’t automatically follow those records.

i.e. If Jim assigns an Opportunity from a Lead to Michael Oakes, the automatic following rule doesn’t work on this opportunity. This needs to happen so that Jim knows when Michael has done any work on it.

Can this be fixed? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Automatic Follow rule being the user chatter feed setting as below. 
This does work as described as long as it is individually turned on by each user.

Assuming both Jim and Michael have this checked, then when Jim converts a lead to an Account/Opportunity, or when he creates a new opportunity and then assigns it, he is the creator of those records and **will** follow them.

- The key point is that **each** user needs to individually set "Automatically follow records that I create"

[image]

Comment: @Dacology- Thank you so much, it is working for me. Much Appreciated

Comment: Super.. glad it saved you hours of coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a basic Apex trigger on the Opportunity.  When Owner changes and by another person, create a follow record for the new owner.